# How to append Application folder name along with the user chosen Target path during Installation using WIX.?

Tags: windows-installer

I want to create/append the Application folder name at the end of the Target path, when the user choose different installation folder path rather than the default path.

The default path is " C:\ProgramFiles\Application Name\"

I wish to append the Folder name as follows "D:\Temp\Application Name\" , if the user choose another path for example "D:\Temp\"

I've referred the  Wix UI as "WixUI_InstallDir"

I've also Set the Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER".

By changing the value of the Property "_BrowseProperty" to "[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]\Application Name" in the BrowseDlg.wxs, I'm getting the error:2872

Any Help...???

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to author every single component in a subdirectory of INSTALLLOCATION.  That way a component would be [INSTALLLOCATION]Application Name.

Another approach would be to use a custom action to see if they selected a path that ended with the application name and if they didn't add it.  Too complicated IMO.

I don't know that I really agree with this requirement though. It's not a convention that is widely used and may frustrate a user who choses  C:\Applications\Application Name and ends up getting C:\Applications\Application Name\Application Name.  I'd be annoyed and choose C:\Applications to get C:\Applications\Application Name.

The widely accepted standard is to make INSTALLLOCATION = [ProgramFilesFolder]My Company\My Application.

Comment: I agree with you. But if the user choose another folder(eg: D:\Temp\) other than the "My Application", which is created under C:\ProgramFiles\ during installation, all the files are copied into the folder("Temp") wihtout any common or main folder in the name of My Application. Or else user need to create a folder on their own for the application that they are going to install.

Comment: You could write a custom action to warn them that the path doesn't end in "appname".   Yes, users can do all kinds of stupid things but in all my years of writing setups this is not one that I've really cared to guard against.